# MSChart: how can I change some AxisLabels

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I want to change some AxisLabelsin some  series  for my Chart

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("ReportMonthly", SCon);
            s.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            s.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y", Y);
            SCon.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);            
            chtWRMonthly.DataSource = dt;
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Sold"].XValueMember = "x";            
            chtWRMonthly.Series["sRemaining"].XValueMember = "x";            
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Bought"].XValueMember = "x";            
            chtWRMonthly.Series["bRemaining"].XValueMember = "x";

            chtWRMonthly.Series["Sold"].YValueMembers = "sTAccount";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["sRemaining"].YValueMembers = "sRemaining";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Bought"].YValueMembers = "bTAccount";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["bRemaining"].YValueMembers = "bRemaining";
            SCon.Close();

            //انتصاب نام ماه ها
            foreach (Series SR in chtWRMonthly.Series)
            {
                foreach (DataPoint DP in SR.Points)
                {
                    switch (DP.AxisLabel)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            DP.AxisLabel = "x1";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            DP.AxisLabel = "x2";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            DP.AxisLabel = "x3";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            DP.AxisLabel = "x4";
                            break;
                  }                        
                }
             }
```

I tried to change them via a Switch but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you add your code here for starters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataPoints` do not have real `AxisLabels`. The strings they show are automatically created from the `DataPoint.XValues`.

So your switch never hits.

Replace

```
 switch (DP.AxisLabel)
```

by

```
 switch (DP.XValue + "")
```

and it'll work.

Note that I have converted the `double` `XValue` to a `string` to fit in with your `switch` code. You can use it directly if you change the `switch` options to `numbers`.

**After** you have set `AxisLabels` you may use them for your test, but not until then..

See [here for a good overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the various chart labels.